# Global Interpreter Lock(GIL) implementation example?

Tags: gil

We are porting some legacy C code to linux(NPTL). The old code depends very heavily on the non-preemptive threading model. One solution we are looking at is to mimic such model in linux by implementing some sort of global lock. I guess it could be like the GIL in CPython or Ruby.

Is there any reference implementation of GIL?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf)? It's not what you are looking for, but might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I stumbled upon that while googling. We have some ideas of how to implement it, but we would like to take a look at some reference implementations to avoid unseen traps or things we missed.